# "No SSL support included in this version of python" using python 3.7 Task Scheduler

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a program to run on regular intervals that sends emails using smtplib; The program runs fine in my IDE and from the command prompt, but when I use task scheduler it gives me an error with no SSL support. I've had the same problem when running another program on task scheduler, it seems like anything that requires a network connection to run won't work with task scheduler due to the need for SSL.

This error in particular occurs when I use `server.starttls()`
I haven't found any help from other answers as I'm not running this from a batch file (not sure what that is), so any and all help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I think the issue is something to the effect that when task scheduler is running your script, it's not using the proper python environment.  [How to Schedule Python Script using Windows Scheduler](https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, that's the first thing that has actually laid out clearly how to go about it.